# return n matched after a speific word in regex - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, jison

I'm trying to get only 2 commas matched after a specific word match

```
this is a test, fun(a, b, fun(a, b, another(a, b, c))) another(a, ,a, ,)
```

I need it return only 4 commas (inside `fun` not `another`) matched instead all 11

```
/fun*(,)/ // I need to write it correct
```

I need to write this regex for a parser using http://zaa.ch/jison/try/
see the ignore regex mentioned

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
([fun])*(,)           /* I need to skip this here */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
```

see the below

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=106380

Comment: What do you want to get as a result?

Comment: I need it to create a parser using https://github.com/zaach/jison

Comment: Please include your code (espacially your regex) instead of an external link.

Comment: Be explicit in what you need as *output* for the given example. I find it hard to believe that you would want as output ",,,,".

Comment: `([fun])*` matches a string of arbitrary length (possibly empty) consisting only of the letters `f`, `n` and `u`. It would match, for example, uff, fnuu and nuun. It seems unlikely that is what you want to do. You might want to seek an introduction to regular expressions.